# PHP allow visitors to ask 5 questions per day system using cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I want to allow visitors to  ask 5 questions per day using cookie, but i don't know how to achieve that. 
this is the code i'm useing right now.

```
$ur_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$number_allowed = 5;  
if(isset($_COOKIE['visitor'."_".$ur_ip])) {
    if ($_COOKIE['visitor'."_".$ur_ip] <= $number_allowed) {
        setcookie("visitor"."_".$ur_ip, $_COOKIE['visitor'."_".$ur_ip] + 1 , time() + 86400 );
        echo "your question";
    } 
    else echo "you passed the number allowed ";
} else {
    setcookie("visitor"."_".$ur_ip, 1 , time() + 86400 );
    echo "your question";
}
```

so when the visitor is already ask one question the cookie value increament and my problem start here because i want to keep the cookie expire date .
i hope you understand what i meant above if not , just provide how to make that system work i mean any visitor can ask only 5 questions per day not more.

Comment: you'd have to store the original "first question" datetime IN the cookie, otherwise you just keep making it expire "1 day" from now, after every question.

Comment: @MarcB thanks that's what i'm going to do.